# Wordpress: get attached images and show them inside post

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to show attached images inside the post ..
Just like

```
<a href"LINK TO FULL SIZE IMAGE"><img src"LINK TO THUMB"></img></a>
```

I get the following from codex.wordpress but how to tell the code to use large image link with `<href` and thumb link with `<img`

```
<?php 
$attachment_id = 8; // attachment ID

$image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id ); // returns an array
?> 

<img src="<?php echo $image_attributes[0]; ?>" width="<?php echo $image_attributes[1]; ?>" height="<?php echo $image_attributes[2]; ?>">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`wp_get_attachment_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_link) instead of `wp_get_attachment_image_src` :

```
echo wp_get_attachment_link($attachment_id, 'large');
```

Comment: but this is not what i require .. My code also displays the image

Comment: I want to show attached thumbnail image inside the post when click it should open the full size image

Comment: now i used this but its also not working <?php 
$attachment_id = 229; // attachment ID

$image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_link( $attachment_id, 'thumbnail' ); // returns an array
 ?>
<a href="<?php echo $image_attributes('thumbnail'); ?>"></a>

Comment: `wp_get_attachment_link` returns html, you just have to echo it